# How to check if jquery package is being referenced

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 3 Razor partial page that is dependent on **jquery.validate.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js**.

Is it possible for the partial page to check whether or not there is, already, a reference to the .js packs?

Since this is a partial page, it's possible/probable that either the _Layout.cshtml or another included partial page has already referenced the .js packs. To avoid duplicate references to the .js packs, I would like the partial page(s) to be able to determine if it needs to add the reference to the packs or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `jQuery` and `jQuery.validate` are defined and load the script if it's not, but it's not really worth the effort - browsers are caching js files, so if you have two references, it will only download it once.

Answer (score 3):

The following bit of js code would check to see if the two plugins have been added to the jQuery object.

```
if (jQuery.validator != undefined && jQuery.validate != undefined) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This will actually break if jQuery is not loaded, because jQuery object will not be defined. You also need to check if jQuery is defined first.

Comment: True, but there's no reason you can't check to make sure jQuery isn't undefined too. The technique still applies. Your answer doesn't address the question at all. Mine is still correct.

Comment: Actually I misread the question a little; I corrected my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but there's a jquery function called getScript that loads a server script through a get request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

As it runs globally it might solve yout problem. You just have to do this:

```
$.getScript('url.js', function(){
//
});
```